# "continuation with" VS "continuation of"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

Examples:

> **The continuation of the strike caused a lot of hardship
>   **
>
> **Today's lecture is in continuation with the previous lectures.**

Explain the difference.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the second example something you have seen written by a native English speaker?  To me, it sounds awkward and unnatural.  I would rather have written, *"Today's lecture is a **continuation of** the previous lectures"*, or, *"Today's lecture **continues** the topics discussed in previous lectures"*

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it doesn't sound something I would hear from a native speaker. Have you found any example on Google?

Comment: No, I couldn't found on Google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be based on an incorrect English expression.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is different from the first in that it is wrong. The correct version, if I have interpreted correctly,  would be:

> Today's lecture is **a** continuation **of** the previous lectures.

If *continuation* is followed by anything it's usually *of*:

[image: Google ngram graph of "continuation of", showing it highly dominant over "continuation in/to/with".]

This graph from [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=continuation%20of%2Ccontinuation%20to%2Ccontinuation%20in%2Ccontinuation%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%20with%3B%2Cc0), and shows the incidence of these different phrases in the corpus that Google has compiled (based on books, I believe).

In modern usage, *every* continuation is a ***continuation of*** something. Even when another word follows it instead, there's an implicit *of something*, except where the word refers to the idea of a continuation in the abstract.

Comment: Can I say "something is in continuation" ?

Comment: Something can be described as "in continuation of" something else, yes. It's not that common as a phrasing, but it's reasonably well-attested.